# Can you create a migration to change data with a "where" condition in Rails 3

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

I have several tables loaded with data where many of the records have the field "status" set to 0. I want to change them to the value 1. Is it possible to write a migration something like this?

```
class UpdateStatusContent < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    MiscDescription.where ["status = ?", 0].update ["status = ?", 1]
    QuestionsBasic.where ["status = ?", 0].update ["status = ?", 1]
    QuestionsStrength.where ["status = ?", 0].update ["status = ?", 1]
  end

  def self.down
  end
end
```

I could do it directly in MySQL but would prefer to use a migration. I've searched and experimented a bit and have not been able to find a solution that works.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that should be possible. Only you should use [`update_all`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all) instead of `update`:

```
MiscDescription.where("status = 0").update_all("status = 1")
```

(No need to use this syntax: `["status = ?", 0]` when there is no user input involved)

Comment: Appropriate avatar and, BTW, your English is great. Appreciate the extra input too regarding the user input. Thanks.